# Pyhton-DeepLEarning-Transfer learning Error Input Dimensiones

Tags: python, keras

Estoy tratando de aplicar "Transfer Learning" a una base de datos de perros y gatos y me da un error sobre las dimensiones esperadas por el mismo. Ya he realizado todo el código, adjunto una parte del mismo.

```py
for i in np.arange(0, len(imagePaths), bs):
    batchPaths = imagePaths[i:i + bs]
    batchLabels = labels[i:i + bs]
    batchImages = []

#recorrer imagenes
for (j,imagePaths) in enumerate(batchPaths):
    image = load_img(imagePaths, target_size=(224,224))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = imagenet_utils.preprocess_input(image)
    batchImages = np.append(batchImages, image)
    batchImages = np.vstack(batchImages)
    features = model.predict(batchImages, batch_size=bs)
    features = features.reshape((features.shape[0], 512*7*7))
    dataset.add(features, batchLabels)
    pbar.update(i)

dataset.close()
pbar.finish()
```

Y el mensaje de error que tengo es el siguiente

```py
features = model.predict(batchImages)
Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (150528, 1)
```

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta pues estás en SO en español

Comment: Listo ya lo traduci, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer

Answer (score 0):

Preparar los datos y configurar una red neuronal es una tarea más tediosa incluso que crear la propia red neuronal.

Ese error significa que **has cargado una red neuronal para que le entre un input de cuatro dimensiones y le estás pasando un input de dos dimensiones**, por lo que tienes que redimensionar tus datos de entrada a 4D

## Explicación teórica

```
#array de dos dimensiones
Two_D = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6])

print(Two_D.shape)
Out[5]: (2, 3)

#array de tres dimensiones
Three_D = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9], [10,11,12]])

print(Three_D.shape)
Out[7]: (2, 2, 3)

#array de 4 dimensiones
Four_D = np.array([[[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9], [10,11,12]]], [[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9], [10,11,12]]]])

print(Four_D.shape)
Out[9]: (2, 2, 2, 3)
```

Y así podría seguir añadiendo listas unas dentro de otras eternamente, cada vez que añado una, añado una dimensión más a mis datos

### Llevando las dimensiones al mundo de los datos

- 1D: Es un un simple **vector** de datos, es decir una linea de números
- 2D: Es lo que conocemos como una tabla (**matriz**), es decir filas y columnas. (las clásicas tablas de datos)
- 3D: Es conocido también como **Tensor**. En realidad podríamos decir que son tablas de datos apiladas una detrás de otra, dentro de una misma estructura de datos que forma una "caja".
- 4D: Por suerte o desgracia, vivimos en un mundo Tridimensional, por lo que nos es difícil entender fuera de las matemáticas como es una forma cuatridimensional. Lo máximo que podemos hacer es plegar la tercera dimensión en un vector de nuevo, y tendríamos un **conjunto de tensores en un Vector**, por lo que podríamos definirlo como una apilación de tensores en forma de vector.

Aquí te dejo una imagen publicada por Tensorlfow, de todo lo que he explicado arriba, para que sea más fácil.

[image: Imagen sobre dimensiones de Tensorflow]

Por ello como comencé diciendo. Tú le estás entregando una matriz al modelo (2D), cuando el modelo espera un vector de Tensores (4D), por lo que tu red falla. Tus datos deben de ser 4D para el modelo funcione.

## Práctica

**No puedo ayudarte más, porque has adjuntado solo parte del código y por tanto no sé de donde vienen las variables**, ni cuál es el modelo, ni que estás intentando hacer. Pero por lo que veo estás haciendo demasiadas transformaciones y estás complicándolo demasiado, cuando usando las funciones de Keras, tienes todo hecho de manera sencilla, En concreto le estás pasando, como te indica el error una matriz (es decir 2D) de 150528 filas y una sola columna, cuando un batch de imagenes suele tener un shape de (n, y, x, c). Donde:

- n: es el número de imagenes en el batch
- y: el ancho de las imagenes
- x: el alto de las imagenes
- c: los canales de color, por lo general 1 si es en blanco y negro o 3, si es en color.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como se haría de forma sencilla con Tensorflow-Keras:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50, resnet50

#Creamos el generador imaginando que usamos el Modelo ResNet50 y preprocesamos las imagenes
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=resnet50.preprocess_input)


dataflow = datagen.flow_from_directory('Data/train/',
                                      target_size= (224, 224),
                                      color_mode='rgb',
                                       batch_size=32,
                                      class_mode='categorical',
                                      shuffle=True)

#Entrenamos el modelo.
model.fit_generator(dataflow, steps_per_epoch=dataflow.n//dataflow.batch_size, epochs=5)
```